# Jquery - toggleClass() is hiding the DIV but not the items within the DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a codepen here which is broken down from my website im working on.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgPwxO

My html:

```
<div id="navbar">
        <div style=" text-align: center; margin-bottom: 30px;">[ABARTHTEXTLOGO]</div>
            <div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
                    <div class="navbutton">TEST 1</div>
                    <div class="navbutton">TEST 2</div>
                    <div class="navbutton">TEST 3</div>
                    <div class="navbutton">TEST 4</div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#navbar
    {
        position: fixed;
        width: 15%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: rgb(000, 000, 000);
        background: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7);
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        float: left;
    }
    #navbar.clicked
    {
        width: 0%;
    }
```

My JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#navbar').click(function()
  {
    $('#navbar').toggleClass('clicked', 200);
  });
});
```

For the purpose of this you just click the navbar to close it.

You can re-open it by clicking on the text in the DIV

However when i close it i want all the text items to disappear with it. At the moment they all just move to the left.

**How do i get them to vanish with the div?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` property into `.navbar` element.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgPwjG

Comment: Brilliant thank you! will mark as answer in 10 mins when i can

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to be fully disappeared after clicking, add this to your CSS:

```
#navbar.clicked * {
       display: none;
    }
```

If you want still see part of the text, cut into the div, use:

```
#navbar.clicked {
       overflow: hidden;
    }
```